# Is there a way to use a DataTemplate to define the structure of a Border object that's created in code?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, binding, datatemplate

So I'm currently trying to learn how to use bindings and DataContext to simplify how my app is structured.

I have a lot of dynamically created controls in my app that I create at runtime in C#, such as this simple border with a textbox inside. The data comes from data classes that I created, `EntryData` in this case.

Data class

```
class EntryData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string EntryID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ColourHex { get; set; }
}
```

Creating the control and putting it into a grid

```
Border outer_border = new Border();
outer_border.Tag = cur_entryData.EntryID;
outer_border.Background = GetSolidColorBrushFromHex(cur_entryData.ColourHex);
outer_border.Style = Application.Current.Resources["bor_EntryCalendarBlock"] as Style;

TextBlock txtblc_title = new TextBlock();
txtblc_title.Style = Application.Current.Resources["txtblc_CalendarBlockTitle"] as Style;
txtblc_title.Text = cur_entryData.Title;

//never got the binding to update

//txtblc_title.DataContext = cur_entryData;    
//Binding bind_title = new Binding();
//bind_title.Source = cur_entryData;
//bind_title.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
//bind_title.Path = new PropertyPath("Title");
//bind_title.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;    
//txtblc_title.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, bind_title);

outer_border.Child = txtblc_title;

Grid.SetRow(outer_border, entry_row);
Grid.SetColumn(outer_border, entry_col);

my_grid.Children.Add(outer_border);
```

You can see my attempt at using binding on the control, which would work to create it, but would never update when the EntryData was changed so I abandoned that. So to say update the title I go to the correct index in `my_grid.Children`, extract the border, extract its child textblock, and then change the text property to the new value.

This is clunky as hell to create and update all these controls but I don't know any other way. I've read a bit about using datacontents to style the entries in buttons and listviews, but I want Border (or technically Grid) as the outer layer as it makes this type of control easier to create and modify.

Is there a way to do something like this

xaml

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="control_template_test" x:DataType="local:EntryData">
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Title}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

C#

```
Border new_border = new Border();

new_border.ContentTemplate = this.Resources["control_template_test"] as DataTemplate;
new_border.DataContext = cur_entryData;
```

I was able to get this working with a button, but not a border or grid, I assume as the button has a `.Content` property. Also even with the button I wasn't able to get the textblock to update when the EntryData was updated. Also I want to put details into the Border itself, such as use the tag for keeping the entryID, for easy access, and the background colour; I don't know how that would be accomplished with a DataTemplate.

Can anyone give me some help? I've tried searching for a couple hours now and haven't found anything that explains if this is possible.

EDIT:

To clarify, I understand this attempt at using ContentTemplate on a Border likely won't exist. I am looking for help at achieving something similar with a different solution. Say I create a template control which has a border and a textblock, and whenever I want I can just create one with a databinding to a data class. Ideally this data binding would update whenever the data class is updated, but that just wouldn't update when I tried before.

Comment: Of course it's possible. But there's not enough context in your question to know why it failed. Possibly it's as simple as failing to set the `Child` property of the `Border` object. As far as I know, no `Border` object in any managed API, whether UWP or otherwise, has a `ContentTemplate` property, so the code you posted doesn't seem valid. In any case, without a good [mcve], there's no way to provide a good answer to the question. please improve the question.

Comment: FWIW, you should discard all of your code that constructs _any_ `FrameworkElement` object in code-behind. Everything should be declared in XAML, whether as a template or directly in the visual layout. Anything that can be done in code-behind with respect to defining the UI layout, can be done in XAML and more easily.

Comment: Yeah I realize that Border likely didn't support this exact implementation. I'll add clarity to the question, but I was looking more into an alternative solution that behave how I'm wanting. Regarding your second comment, I would definitely do that if I knew how! I've tried to set up MVVM but it goes over my head, and I have never found any good explanation on how to use templates or custom controls with data bindings that update.

Comment: _"I have never found any good explanation on how to use templates...with data bindings that update"_ -- not sure why that would be. There are lots of them out there. It's a fundamental feature of UWP and other XAML-based APIs. If you have implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` (INPC) correctly, then any binding where the object's properties are referenced will update automatically when property values change, including in any `DataTemplate` that uses that type of object. ...

Comment: ... Rather than asking for help with this non-starter scenario, you should focus on learning MVVM and post a question that shows what you've tried in that paradigm, and explain what's not working and what it is you don't understand about it.

Comment: Okay I'll try to look more into that style of coding again. Is MVVM the only term for this sort of thing? The few guides that I was able to find had incredibly complicated and not well explained stuff going on in the viewmodel that I couldn't wrap my head around. Instead of this, is it acceptible to just fix the INotifyPropertyChanged binding issue while keeping all code in the code behind? My app only has one page anyway. Just wanting to make sure when searching to not find something overly complicated that I won't understand.

Comment: _"is it acceptible to just fix the INotifyPropertyChanged binding issue while keeping all code in the code behind?"_ -- there aren't any MVVM police who will cite or jail you for doing it "wrong", so i wouldn't worry about what's "acceptable". The point is to use the API in the most efficient way, which in the long run means accepting the intended paradigm. But you certainly can build UI in code-behind instead of using XAML. The problem there is that when doing so, you will need to set up the bindings manually, while XAML provides markup extensions that do that for you (i.e. `"{Binding...}"`).

Comment: I took your advice and went digging more and eventually after trial and error got it working, kind of. Some things don't work perfectly but I'm working on it. I have another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62924711/data-binding-a-boolean-to-an-isenabled-and-boolean-to-style-not-working

Comment: Border does not contains `ContentTemplate`, for your requirement, we suggest you use TemplatedControl to custom border and add `ContentTemplate` property.